# C# - How can I check if it is Column 0 in the datatable?

Tags: c#, excel

I have a data table that I am creating from an excel file.  This works fine.  But, I recently had a spec change and need to substitute a value in column 0 of the table.  I am having trouble getting my IF statement to fire.  It is probably something simple I am overlooking.

Basically, if it is the first column in the row, I want to put a specific value I pulled elsewhere (I am pulling the color of the cell and putting in the RGB value).  If it is any other column in the row, continue to read in the data as usual.
Please see the below code:

```
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
{
    tbl.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? firstRowCell.Text : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
    //var cellColor = ws.Cells[firstRowCell].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.LookupColor();
}

//var startRow = hasHeader ? 2 : 1;
for (int rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
{
    var currentRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
    DataRow row = tbl.Rows.Add();
    for (var i = 0; i < tbl.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        //This is my problem. I am not seeing what needs to be in here.  
        if (tbl.Columns.????????)
        {
            row[i] = colorTable[rowNum];
        }
        else
        {
            row[i] = currentRow[rowNum, i + 1].Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just use `if (i == 0)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in a for loop that starts at your first column to the last

```
for (var i = 0; i < tbl.Columns.Count; i++)
```

So the value you can use to know at what column you're at would be the `i`, you could have something like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < tbl.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    //If you're at the first column 
    if (i == 0)
    {
        row[i] = colorTable[rowNum];
    }
    else
    {
        row[i] = currentRow[rowNum, i + 1].Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the words of Homer Simpson - DOH!  Thanks.

Comment: @JamesCraig haha, no problem.

Comment: @JamesCraig If my answer solved your problem feel free to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to show that you've found a solution.